# angularjs "node is undefined" error in Firebug when moving templates into main html file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm working on a landing page that is written largely with Angular JS 1.0.2. Upgrading to a later version may not be in the cards, at least not right away. It's working fine, but we're trying to do a bit of optimization. For a bit of background, we have a number of directives set up for various modal windows and other custom elements on the page. These use tempateUrl parameters and grab them from separate html files which contain all of the necessary HTML. Quick and dirty example as there's way too much code for me to post a full one:

Landing page html:

```
<div help-menu />
```

Angular directive:

```
module.directive('helpMenu', function(){
templateUrl: helpMenu.html,
controller: ...
link: ...
});
```

Where helpMenu.html contains simple html for the element in question.

This hasn't been a problem, but the number of html files keeps going up and I'd like to merge them into the main html file for the landing page to reduce the number of GET requests. Doing so basically involves snipping the HTML from each of the files and placing it at the end of the landing page html file (while wrapped in a div with an id to grab). The directive is changed to use:

```
template: $('#helpMenu')
```

This works just fine if helpMenu contains no angular code. However, I get a "node is undefined" or "linkNode is undefined" error in Firebug if I the html contains any angular code, ie, an ng-repeat, ng-show, etc. The odd thing is that everything works as expected despite the error, but I'd really like to get rid of it regardless.

I've tried a few ways to fix this (attempting a $compile at various points hasn't helped), but with no success, and there is very little information on this particular error. I'm baffled as to why it's a problem when the html that comes in will be identical in both methods. Perhaps template and templateUrl handle things differently?

Comment: What happens if you try `$('#helpMenu').html()` instead?

Comment: that should works. Try that... but i would like to recoment to write the template within the directive. It's more clear from my point of view.

Comment: Oh, for crying out...thanks sh0ber. That fixed the issue. Urg, sometimes I have the darnedest time finding problems that are right in front of my nose.

And Musli, I would, but there is sometimes a pretty large chunk of HTML and placing it in the directive would probably be more cumbersome than helpful.